Laptop keeps "finding and ejecting USB devices" even though I haven't plugged any?
Laptop is DELL VOSTRO 3550. 120 GB SSD, Intel i5-2450M, 8 GB RAM, Running Windows 10
I've been using this laptop for quite some time, mainly to get technological help from the Internet. I use it as a "basement laptop". Recently, I plugged my 64 GB SANDISK CRUZER SNAP USB to make a Windows 10 bootable USB, but after unplugging it, my laptop makes the annoying sound when a USB is connected. It makes it every 1 - 2 seconds, or sometimes a minute. It even makes the USB Disconnected sound as well. I have not plugged any USB devices after making that bootable USB.


The USB port might be physically damaged. Have you tried to plug another USB device into that port, to see if it stops the issue? 2. Have you rebooted (not just Sleep or Hibernate, but shutdown /s /t 00)? 3. You can also delete the list of connected USB devices, if those don't help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1285104/how-to-delete-all-record-of-usb-device-connected-h

